# Filter a slicer via a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

**I want to be able to filter the slicer by the content of a cell value which I type manually in the worksheet.**

I have slicer "country_of_origin" that controls three pivot tables "applications", "decisions", "invitations".
I would like to filter the slicer by the "country of origin" which I type manually in the cell B2, without scrolling the whole list of countries on the slicer list.

I tried to record macro, but it was not a solution for me, because it won't work, if I typed the name of the country manually in the cell in the worksheet. It looked like that:

```
slicer_Country_of_origin")
        .SlicerItems("ALBANIA").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("AFGHANISTAN").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("ALGIERIA").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("ARMENIA").Selected = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Further I found on mrexcel.com forum some code, I copied it, changing the name of slicer to "country of origin" and position of the cell to "$b$2".

```
sub Macro6()   
' sheet module
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim sc As SlicerCache, si As SlicerItem
        If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then                    
            Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Country of origin")      ' desired slicer
            sc.ClearAllFilters
            For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
                If si.Caption = CStr(Target) Then
                    si.Selected = True
                Else
                    si.Selected = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

After starting this macro, after the line 
`sub Macro6()` 
I recieved the message:

> Compile error: Expected End Sub.

I would like to transform/correct the code, so it will meet my needs, which is to filter the slicer by the content of a cell value which I type manually in the worksheet.**

Comment: In which line do you get the compile error?

Comment: in the first line, just right after starting the macro.

Comment: Right after this line? `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`  • I cannot see any error here. Are you sure you use exactly the code you show? With exactly the same line breaks? • Actually this procedure is an event and runs automatically but cannot be run manually. • Please try to be more precise about *where exactly* your issue is.

Comment: Over the line ' sheet module there is a line including title: Sub Macro6 () and right after this line the error occurs.
My issue is to write a code which able to filter the slicer by the content of a cell value which I type manually in the worksheet. I wrote in the post about trials. I need help at transforming the code in this way that my slicer use ase a filter the content which I write in cell B2.

Comment: This line `Sub Macro6 ()` is not shown in your question. Please [edit] your question and add all the relevant code **exactly** as it is in your code editor. We cannot help you if you show something different from what you actually have in your editor.

Comment: Delete line `sub Macro6()`. It marks a beginning of a sub - like the next line also does ...

Comment: If I delete this line `sub Macro6()` the whole macro disappears.

Comment: There probably is an `End Sub` we don't see in your code?

Comment: The only one `End Sub` is in the last line of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid. It must be

```
sub Macro6()   
' sheet module
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sc As SlicerCache, si As SlicerItem
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then                    
        Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Country of origin")      ' desired slicer
        sc.ClearAllFilters
        For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
            If si.Caption = CStr(Target) Then
                si.Selected = True
            Else
                si.Selected = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that `Worksheet_Change` is an event and does not appear in the list where you can run macros. This macro cannot be run manually it automatically runs every time a cell is changed.

Comment: I didn't know that. But the macro doesn't result on my slicer, anyway. Any idea what might be wrong?.
I have also the second question basing on the information from the post above. Is there a possiblity to write a code including an option of manual update of slicer? In this way that I write the name of the country, I click the button and then slicer get updated?

Comment: @GosiaJankowska Sorry we can only answer one question per post. You will need to ask a new question and you need to try it on your own first and ask if you get stuck or errors. • *"Does not work"* is no error description, and is useless for us to help you.